# Deploy Laravel + Inertia + Vue3 app with Docker SQL Database

Tags: laravel, docker, deployment, vuejs3, inertiajs

I am new to this stack and I just finalized my Laravel + Inertia + Vue3  app. I now have no idea how to deploy it or where, as well as how to deploy my MySQL mariadb:10.8.3 database, that runs through docker in local environment. Can you please suggest me a platform to host my app as well as how to deploy the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the guy who found this question useful - I got you homie! I upload to Heroku  by first npm run build the vue3, upload with git and for the database - I currenly use the JawsDB Maria add-on from Heroku that works like charm! Oh and do not forget to update the AppServiceProvider in laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        if (config('app.env') === 'production') {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }
}
```